# iOS button design

Tags: ios, xcode

[image]

What is the best way to design custom buttons and using them within Xcode. I want them not to look like random buttons. They should look like button as the were from Apple themselves.

Comment: I updated my question. This is what I tried so far but it doesn't fit in the design elements of  very well...

Comment: What's wrong with using a standard UIButton?

Comment: I want my button to stand out

Comment: Make up your mind. It either looks like a standard Apple button or it stands out. Which one do you want?

Comment: you can use images whatever you like as a button. @RepazKung

Answer (score 1):

You can use just the **UIButton**, you can set easily:

- background color, background image
- font type, font color
- round corner
- dimensions even dynamics with the right constraints

What kind of button do you want to make? See [this link](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/building-ios-interfaces-custom-button) for a basic tutorial meantime.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new file called `design.swift` then add these:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class CustomTextView : UITextView
{

    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat {
        get {
            return layer.cornerRadius
        }
        set {
            layer.cornerRadius = newValue
            layer.masksToBounds = newValue > 0
        }
    }


    @IBInspectable var borderWidth: CGFloat{
        set {
            layer.borderWidth = newValue
        }
        get{
            return self.layer.borderWidth
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var borderColor: UIColor? {
        set {
            layer.borderColor = newValue?.CGColor
        }
        get{
            let c = UIColor(CGColor: layer.borderColor!)
            return c
        }
    }

}

@IBDesignable class CustomView : UIView{

    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat {
        get {
            return layer.cornerRadius
        }
        set {
            layer.cornerRadius = newValue
            layer.masksToBounds = newValue > 0
        }
    }



    @IBInspectable var borderWidth: CGFloat{
        set {
            layer.borderWidth = newValue
        }
        get{
            return self.layer.borderWidth
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var borderColor: UIColor? {
        set {
            layer.borderColor = newValue?.CGColor
        }
        get{
            let c = UIColor(CGColor: layer.borderColor!)
            return c
        }
    }
}



@IBDesignable class CustomButton : UIButton{

    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat {
        get {
            return layer.cornerRadius
        }
        set {
            layer.cornerRadius = newValue
            layer.masksToBounds = newValue > 0
        }
    }



    @IBInspectable var borderWidth: CGFloat{
        set {
            layer.borderWidth = newValue
        }
        get{
            return self.layer.borderWidth
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var borderColor: UIColor? {
        set {
            layer.borderColor = newValue?.CGColor
        }
        get{
            let c = UIColor(CGColor: layer.borderColor!)
            return c
        }
    }
}
```

then click at your button go to class right Custom